# How to fix Currency in a Custom Object

Tags: currency

I have got a custom Object filled with market data, I like to use Dashboards to picture the Trends in the worldmarket we are working in. This Object is not related to any other Object. We are using two differen Currencies (EUR & USD).

All data is in US Dollar and I would like to make sure it will be shown everywhere in USD and not converted into Euro.

Is it possible to determine USD for this object?

Or should I use Number fields instead?

Comment: what is your org default currency ?

Comment: Mine is Euro but we have users with Dollar also.

Comment: are you asking how to show all values in a dashboard in a non-org-default currency based on a report that pulls from objects - some records are in USD, some records are in EUR but where EUR is the org currency?  That is, summarize in the dashboard in USD?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that it is not connected to any object you can define a process using lightning process builder on this object and setup **CURRENCYISOCODE** to **USD** as shown below on record creation.

[image]